# Dedekind Cuts in Rudin' analysis - Step 4 - Follow-Up

Tags: real-analysis

This question is a continuation of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/187186), but I don't have enough reputation to comment, so asking as a standalone question.

In that answer, [Brian M. Scott](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/12042/brian-m-scott) takes pains to point out that `j>0`.

Why does it matter that `j>0`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I think I've figured it out.  We know $j>0$ and $j\in\mathbb{N}$.  Thus $j \geq 1$.  Recall that $n=j-1-k$.

If $j=1$, then $n=-k$ and $nw=-kw$, and we know $-kw\in\alpha$.  However, $(n+1)w = (j-k)w$.  By definition of $j$ and $S$ we know $(j-k)w\notin \alpha$.  Thus $n$ satisfies the conditions.

If $j > 1$, then we also have $j-1\in\mathbb{N}$.  Then $nw=((j-1)-k))w$.  If $nw\notin\alpha$,  then $j-1\in S$.  However, $j$ is the least member of $S$.  So we must have $nw\in\alpha$.  Of course, $(n+1)w=(j-k)w$, so $(n+1)w\notin\alpha$, and $n$ satisfies the conditions.

(I realize this is a bit pedantic, I just didn't want success to depend on the technicality of whether $\mathbb{N}$ includes $0$.)

Comment: What you’ve written is correct, but the argument **does** depend on having $0\in\Bbb N$. We want $j>0$ so that $j-1\in\Bbb N$ and therefore $$j-1\in\Bbb N\setminus S=\{i\in\Bbb N:(i-k)w\in\alpha\}\,.$$ If $j-1$ were not in $\Bbb N$, the fact that it’s less than $\min S$ wouldn’t tell us anything about $n$.

Comment: Thanks for weighing in @BrianM.Scott!  What I was trying to do with the first case with $j=1$ is say that, even if we are defining $\mathbb{N}$ as starting at $1$, it still works out with this definition of $n$.

Comment: Ah, I see. Okay, though I think that the way I wrote the last paragraph of that answer makes it clear that I was assuming that $0\in\Bbb N$. (For the record, if I want the positive integers, I write $\Bbb Z^+$.)

Comment: Agreed @BrianM.Scott, I'm just new at this and so I'm extra cautious.  Thanks!

Comment: You’re welcome!